# Read content from file and send email

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I have trouble in reading content from a file and send it as the body of an email in java. However, if i run the code to send email without reading content from file, it sends the email successfully, but gives problem while reading content from file for body. It would be great if you can help me below is code which I am using

Thanks in advance!

```
package com.example.tests;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.*;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;

public class sendEmail {

    private static String USER_NAME = "zxxzz@gmail.com";  // GMail user name (just the part before "@gmail.com")
    private static String PASSWORD = "xxxxxxx"; // GMail password
    private static String RECIPIENT = "zxxzz@gmail.com";
    static String strLine = null;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String from = USER_NAME;
        String pass = PASSWORD;
        String[] to = { RECIPIENT }; // list of recipient email addresses
        String subject = "Java send mail example";
        String body = strLine;

        readfile();
        sendFromGMail(from, pass, to, subject, body);
    }

    private static void sendFromGMail(String from, String pass, String[] to, String subject, String body) {
        Properties props = System.getProperties();
        String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
        props.put("mail.smtp.user", from);
        props.put("mail.smtp.password", pass);
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

        try {
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
            InternetAddress[] toAddress = new InternetAddress[to.length];

            // To get the array of addresses
            for( int i = 0; i < to.length; i++ ) {
                toAddress[i] = new InternetAddress(to[i]);
            }

            for( int i = 0; i < toAddress.length; i++) {
                message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddress[i]);
            }

            message.setSubject(subject);
            message.setText(body);
            Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
            transport.connect(host, from, pass);
            transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
            transport.close();
        }
        catch (AddressException ae) {
            ae.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (MessagingException me) {
            me.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public static void readfile(){    
        try{
            // Open the file that is the first 
            // command line parameter
            FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("C:\\Sample.txt");
            // Get the object of DataInputStream
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

            //Read File Line By Line
            while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
                // Print the content on the console
                System.out.println (strLine);
            }
            //Close the input stream
            in.close();
        }catch (Exception e){//Catch exception if any
            System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Exception I get:

```
          Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.geronimo.mail.util.ASCIIUtil.isAscii(ASCIIUtil.java:47)
        at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.setText(MimeMessage.java:939)
        at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.setText(MimeMessage.java:932)
        at com.example.tests.sendEmail.sendFromGMail(sendEmail.java:55)
        at com.example.tests.sendEmail.main(sendEmail.java:25)
```

Answer (score 1):

the `strLine` is null!

you are reading the file correctly, but cyclinf the file the last assignement will be null

```
strLine = br.readLine()) != null
```

maybe an inadvertence.

Replace

```
        //Read File Line By Line
        while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
            // Print the content on the console
            System.out.println (strLine);
        }
```

to

```
        //Read File Line By Line
        String line;
        strLine="";
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)   {
            // Print the content on the console
            strLine += line;
        }
        System.out.println (strLine);
```

or better use [string buffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html#append%28java.lang.CharSequence%29)

```
        //Read File Line By Line
        String line;
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer("");
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)   {
            // Print the content on the console
            buffer.append(line);
        }
        strLine = buffer .toSTring();
        System.out.println (strLine);
```

then call

```
sendFromGMail(from, pass, to, subject, strLine);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, first, there is what @venergiac mentioned... but also, in your `main` function, you do:

```
final String body = strLine;  // body = strLine = null
readfile();                   // initalise strLine
sendFromGMail(from, pass, to, subject, body);  // use body
```

Basically, you set `body = strLine` **before** initializing `strLine`.
You might want to switch these two lines as well (or directly use `strLine` as an argument of `sendFromGmail`?).

By the way, the [Code Convention for the Java Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html) in Java is to use **CamelCase** for any class name: I think that you should get use to it and rename your class `sendEmail` to `SendEmail` :)

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, your `body` variable is always null.

In main function, change `String body = strLine;` to `String body = mailString;`and use another global variable like `mailString` and fill it in `readfile` function

```
StringBuffer mailStirng = new StringBuffer("");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            String from = USER_NAME;
            String pass = PASSWORD;
            String[] to = { RECIPIENT }; // list of recipient email addresses
            String subject = "Java send mail example";
            readfile();
            String body = mailStirng.toString();
            sendFromGMail(from, pass, to, subject, body);
        }

    public static void readfile(){    
            try{
                // Open the file that is the first 
                // command line parameter
                FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("C:\\Sample.txt");
                // Get the object of DataInputStream
                DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

                //Read File Line By Line
                while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
                    // Print the content on the console
                    mailString.append(strLine);
                }
                //Close the input stream
                in.close();
            }catch (Exception e){//Catch exception if any
                System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
```